# Linking to Custom Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How could I link to custom controller actions using short and flexible solutions like `links_path` or `up_link_url(link)`, for this controller route `match "/random" => "links#random"`

Must manually extend the path or is there a helper out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `:as`:

```
match "/random" => "links#random", :as => :random_links
```

to create:

```
random_links_path  #and random_links_url
```